# error OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/ '

Tags: python, pip, chaquopy

I was trying to install new packages in an application with pip, but I got this error

```py
from pip._internal import main as pipmain



pipmain(['install','mechanize','-t .'])
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes need change directory to home:

```py
import os
os.chdir("/data/data/com.lamineml.compiler_python3/files/")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add packages to your app, don't run pip at runtime, use Chaquopy's built-in pip support as documented [here](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#android-requirements).

Comment: Thanks for the answer
I want the application user to add new packages without the intervention of an application programmer. Can I do this?

Comment: pip is [not designed to run inside another program](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program), and Chaquopy doesn't provide a Python executable that would allow you to run it as a separate program. Perhaps you could use a different package manager.